# Microbiome analysis tags needed!

Tags: discussion

We analyze the human microbiome using 16s sequencing. I couldn't find a single relevant tag for my question!

### Tags Needed

#### General

- 16s
- microbiome
- microbial
- taxonomic-assignment
- 16s-sequencing
- dada2
- otu
- asv
- alpha-diversity
- beta-diversity
- shannon
- simpson
- unifrac
- pcoa

#### Software

- phyloseq
- dada2
- qiime
- qiime2
- picrust
- picrust2
- decipher
- lots lots more...
  *

Comment: You can always assign tags, I know the area you are working in. OTU is commonly referred to as taxa.